# How do I instantiate a Scripting.Dictionary using CoCreateInstance?

Tags: c++, winapi, com

I have been reading up on COM and VBScript and I am now curious if I can create a Scripting.Dictionary object from C++ using CoCreateInstance function.

What I want to accomplish is something like this:

**script.vbs**

```
' reminder: run with "cscript script.vbs"
Option Explicit

Dim myDictionary

Set myDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

myDictionary.Add "Foo", "Bar"

MsgBox myDictionary.Item("Foo")
```

I don't actually understand how the process of instantiating COM Objects works, but from what I understood, it has to look something like:

**main.cpp**:

```
/* reminder: use Unicode */
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/**
 * Takes a guid and dumps it out to stdin as a string.
 * @param guid guid to dump to stdin.
 */
void DumpGUID(GUID guid)
{

    char dumpData[81];
    sprintf_s (
        &dumpData[0], 
        81,
        "{"
            "\"Data1\": \"%u\","
            "\"Data2\": \"%u\","
            "\"Data3\": \"%u\","
            "\"Data4\": \"%u\""
        "}", 
        guid.Data1, 
        guid.Data2, 
        guid.Data3, 
        guid.Data4
    );
   puts(dumpData);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    GUID guid;
    const wchar_t *ScriptingDictionaryGUID = L"EE09B103-97E0-11CF-978F-00A02463E06F";

    void *myDictionary = NULL;

    /* anonymous scope: set guid to 0 so I can tell if it has changed */     
    {
        memset(&guid, 0, sizeof(guid));    
    }     

    DumpGUID(guid);

    /* anonymous scope: convert my string to guid */
    {
        HRESULT whyNoConvert = CLSIDFromString((LPCOLESTR)ScriptingDictionaryGUID, &guid);
        if (FAILED(whyNoConvert)) {
            printf("can't convert string to guid, got error %d.\n", whyNoConvert);

            /* ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680589(v=vs.85).aspx */
            switch (whyNoConvert) {
            case NOERROR:
                puts("The CLSID was obtained successfully.");
                break;
            case CO_E_CLASSSTRING:
                puts("The class string was improperly formatted.");
                break;
            case REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG:
                puts("The CLSID corresponding to the class string was not found in the registry.");
                break;
            case REGDB_E_READREGDB:
                puts("The registry could not be opened for reading.");
                break;
            }
            system("pause");
        }
    }
    DumpGUID(guid);

    HRESULT instantiationResult = CoCreateInstance (
        guid,
        NULL,
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER | CLSCTX_INPROC_HANDLER,
        IID_IDispatch,
        &myDictionary
    );
    DumpGUID(guid);

    if (FAILED(instantiationResult)) {
        puts("Can't create a dictionary :(");
    } else {
        puts("I HAVE DONE IT!");
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

My code fails to create the dictionary object(but it does compile)... 
It also fails to actually convert from my String to GUID with error "The class string was improperly formatted.".

I have no idea what I am doing wrong(or what I am doing right for  that matter).

**EDIT**: Working code(still need to figure out how to interface with the object once it's created though)

```
#ifndef UNICODE
    #define UNICODE
#endif
#ifndef NOMINMAX
    #define NOMINMAX
#endif
#ifndef STRICT
    #define STRICT
#endif
#pragma comment(lib, "uuid.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "ole32.lib")

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    GUID dictionary_guid = {0xEE09B103, 0x97E0, 0x11CF, {0x97, 0x8F, 0x00, 0xA0, 0x24, 0x63, 0xE0, 0x6F}};
    IDispatch* p_dictionary = nullptr;

    /* anonymous scope: initializing COM */
    {
        HRESULT result = CoInitialize(NULL);
        if (!SUCCEEDED(result)) {
            printf("CoInitialize failed: %u.\n", result);
            system("pause");
            exit(0);
        }
    }

    /* anonymous scope: creating instance and checking */
    {
        HRESULT result = CoCreateInstance (
            dictionary_guid,
            nullptr,
            CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER | CLSCTX_INPROC_HANDLER,
            IID_IDispatch,
            reinterpret_cast<void**>(&p_dictionary)
        );
        if (!SUCCEEDED(result)) {
            puts("CoCreateInstance failed");
            system("pause");
            exit(0);
        } 

        puts ("I HAVE DONE IT!");
        printf("HRESULT = %u.\n", result);
        printf("p_dictionary: %u.\n", p_dictionary);
    }
    p_dictionary->Release(); 
    CoUninitialize();   

    system("pause");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: First of all you want to use Unicode strings.

Comment: I done more checking and it says that my GUID is not properly formatted, not sure how to deal with this.

Comment: Use `CLSIDFromProgID()` instead: `CLSIDFromProgID(L"Scripting.Dictionary", &guid); `

Comment: The dictionary's properties and methods are [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4k5wbx4.aspx). Use [`IDispatch.Invoke()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221479.aspx) to access them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you work with Visual Studio, there is a cool [#import directive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6.aspx) that generates wrappers that ease COM when a [Type Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366757.aspx) is available.

Most of the time the Type Library is included in the COM object itself (the DLL that serves the object you're after) or in a .TLB aside the DLL. Here is a simple example with the scripting object which resides in C:\Windows\System32\scrrun.dll:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

// import the .TLB that's compiled in scrrun.dll
#import "C:\Windows\System32\scrrun.dll" \
    rename("FreeSpace", "FreeSpace2") // avoid name collision with Windows SDK's GetFreeSpace macro, this is specific to scrrun.dll

using namespace Scripting;

// sample usage of Scripting.Dictionary
void CreateDicAndAdd()
{
    IDictionaryPtr ptr(__uuidof(Dictionary)); // create an instance of the Dictionary coclass and get an IDictionary pointer back
    _variant_t foo = L"foo";
    _variant_t bar = L"bar";
    ptr->Add(&foo, &bar); // call the Add method

    wprintf(L"%i\n", ptr->Count); // call the Count property (wrapper that was generated automatically)

    _variant_t outBar;
    ptr->get_Item(&foo, &outBar); // get the item for "foo"

    // here we know it's a string (outBar.vt could tell you, in case you didn't know)
    // in fact, it's a BSTR, but a BSTR is also a LPWSTR
    // (the reverse is false, welcome to Automation :-)
    wprintf(L"%s\n", outBar.bstrVal);
}

// sample driver code.
int main()
{
    CoInitialize(NULL);
    CreateDicAndAdd();
    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

What's cool is all these wrappers (_variant_t, IDictionaryPtr, etc.) are smart, meaning you don't have to explicitely release or dispose them. In the end, it's very similar to how you would program COM with higher level languages (VBScript, JScript, C#, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for  the response. up to now I kinda managed to get the Dictionary created and insert the item(I think?) but I can't figure out how to "get" the items out of the map. I tried using `get_Item`, which seemed to fail, and I tried using Items to get the items but I couldn't figure out how to traverse them. Can you please demonstrate getting bar out of the dictionary by key foo? This is how far I got: http://hastebin.com/icidixopif.coffee (as you can see I am clearly new to this).

Comment: nvm i got it :O http://hastebin.com/ezujoyakun.coffee. Although I was hoping to get this done without the wrapper.

Comment: Any idea how I can fix this to make it work? http://hastebin.com/dexewajuwi.coffee It's similar to yours but I am trying to do it more explicitly.

Comment: http://hastebin.com/mokayeriko.coffee version works, it does exact same thing except the last variant uses _variant_t instead of VARIANT. How can I eliminate it as well?

Comment: Ok I eliminated it. I think the problem was that get_Item has conditional behavior whether or not bStr is NULL or not, and whether vt is 0 or not. Unless the VARIANT is zeroed out, or the memory in VARIANT is available via SysAllocString, it will try writing into that memory and cause memory violation. http://hastebin.com/idovesasox.coffee

Comment: Either you use _variant_t & _bstr_t wrapper classes (wich I strongly recommend), or you use low level APIs (such as VARIANT struct, BSTR struct, VariantXXX, SysAllocString, SysFreeString, etc.). Just don't mix both worlds like in your example, unless you know what you do. For example, you just can't declare VARIANT getMe; and go on like that, you *must* call VariantInit(&getMe); before anything else. If you use _variant_t, you don't have that problem, you can just declare _variant_t getMe; and it will do VariantInit undecovers (and VariantClear when getMe will go out of scope)

Comment: Ok I think I understand why i was getting weird errors; the IDictionaryPtr object must be created in another scope than that where CoUninitialize is called, otherwise it tries to call Release after couninitialize has been called, and causes an exception to be thrown. It works fine after putting it in an anonymous scope, or external function as you have.

Comment: @Dmitry - absolutely, or you can explicitely Release it before the call to CoUninitialize. That's the only reason why I created the CreateDicAndAdd function. In many real world cases where many components use COM, not everyone calls CoUninitialize anyway...

Comment: actually even if I release it before I calling uninitialize it also throws. thats not quite obvious. That said even if I don't uninitialize it shouldn't matter for this kind of components(could be objectively better not to actually here), but its a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me:

```
#undef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#undef NOMINMAX
#define NOMINMAX
#undef STRICT
#define STRICT
#include <windows.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>

auto fail( std::string const& s )
    -> bool
{ throw std::runtime_error( s ); }

struct Succeeded {};

auto operator>>( HRESULT const hr, Succeeded )
    -> bool
{ return SUCCEEDED( hr ); }     // A macro from <windows.h>.

struct Com_library
{
    ~Com_library()
    { CoUninitialize(); }

    Com_library()
    {
        CoInitialize( 0 )
            >> Succeeded() || fail( "CoInitialize failed" );
    }
};

namespace sys {
    using String = std::wstring;
    auto& out = std::wcout;
    auto& err = std::wcerr;
}  // namespace sys

void cppmain()
{
    Com_library const using_Com;

    GUID const dictionary_guid =
    {0xEE09B103, 0x97E0, 0x11CF, {0x97, 0x8F, 0x00, 0xA0, 0x24, 0x63, 0xE0, 0x6F}};

    IDispatch* p_dictionary = nullptr;
    CoCreateInstance (
        dictionary_guid,
        nullptr,
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER | CLSCTX_INPROC_HANDLER,
        IID_IDispatch,
        reinterpret_cast<void**>( &p_dictionary )
        )
        >> Succeeded() || fail( "CoCreateInstance failed" );

    sys::out << "I HAVE DONE IT!\n";
    /* figure out how to use the dictionary handle */

    p_dictionary->Release();        // You want to automate this, e.g. smart pointer.
}

auto main()
    -> int
{
    using std::exception;
    try
    {
        cppmain();
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    catch( exception const& x )
    {
        sys::err << x.what() << "\n";
    }
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Compiling with g++:

```
g++ com_example.cpp -lole32 -luuid
```

Compiling with Visual C++:

```
cl com_example.cpp ole32.lib uuid.lib
```

One important thing is to remember to initialize COM, via a call to `CoInitialize`. Also, be aware that using `IDispatch` directly is a PITA in C++ (very simple in a scripting language, for which it's designed, but ungood in C++), so if the dictionary class supports a **dual interface** you'd better query for the ordinary more C++-friendly interface. Or use some 3<sup>rd</sup> party's C++ `IDispatch` wrapper, such may exist (since I made one once I guess that also others may have, and placed it on the net).

Comment: http://hastebin.com/ahuvihifoz.vbs on visual studio, and http://hastebin.com/axefipagap.tex in mingw although i suspect that's because no -std=c++11(auto). After adding -std=c++11: http://hastebin.com/gonusaloxi.tex

Comment: @Dmitry: Yes, that's clearly pre-C++11 compiler behavior. I used g++ 5.1.0 and Visual C++ 2015 update 2.

Comment: keep in mind that I am using Visual Studio 2012, so have to go a bit easy on some very new features(it still supports stuff like auto, it doesn't compile for me either because of newer features or misconfiguration)

Comment: Uno momento, let me fire up Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: commenting out     using String = std::wstring; it compiles.

Comment: btw i've seen many ways to write main, but it's the first time I see auto main -> int. woo more things to learn. Anyway, it says CoInitialize failed.

Comment: Uhm, Visual Studio 2012 is stuck at "loading components", sorry.

Comment: is http://hastebin.com/unayadavet.vala critical to the code? seems strange.

Comment: `STRICT` is the default now, and is necessary for C++ type checking. `UNICODE` is absolutely needed. `NOMINMAX` is needed to avoid conflict between C++ standard lib and `min` and `max` macros. You probably also want the lean-'n-mean macro, I can't recall exactly the name. Google it.

Comment: i mean the undef part.

Comment: He he, Visual Studio 2012 finally managed to get started. You're right, it chokes on the C++11 `using` declaration. Happily it's not used in this code. :)

Comment: Yeah, you need the `#undef`s to avoid warnings about macro redefinitions.

Comment: my bad, you're right, macro redefinition warnings are a thing... We need to get on making a php preprocessor for bundling that into #define, or just replace the whole macro system altogether with PHP... im getting off topic Anyway, still can't CoInitialize.

Comment: I suggest you investigate the `CoInitialize` issue in a simpler program, with just that and nothing more.

Comment: http://hastebin.com/bodusemira.coffee seems to work. now to figure out how to use it...

Comment: Uh, `if (result)` is generally incorrect for an `HRESULT`. It's failure if bit 31 is set, i.e. if it's negative as a signed value. But `CoInitialize` can also return a non-zero success value.

Comment: Oh that's a typo, I meant if !SUCCEEDED http://hastebin.com/quzugogodi.coffee works as well. I modified it. I wish i knew how to get IDictionary/PDictionary or whatever the interface for Scripting.Dictionary is so I can interface with it.

Comment: When working with Visual Studio's C++, there are much easier ways to work with COM/automation, for example using the #import w/o resorting to any 3rd party library. Of course, the drawback is your code is not portable any more (if it ever was)

Comment: @Dmitry: You can use the `.QueryInterface` method on the interface you have.